# How to select an item from a CSS custom dropdown list using Selenium WebDriver with java?

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I want to select an item in a CSS dropdown but there seems to be no way to do it, we can take as an example the google hotel review page [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?source=hp&q=abamar%20hotel%20review&oq=abamar%20hotel%20review&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30k1l3.1999.8005.0.11350.19.19.0.0.0.0.88.1375.19.19.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.19.1374...0j0i131k1j0i10k1.l69kxAocPPs#lrd=0x12e727ce468f80c7:0x3a99ebf7568a6c8d,1,,) how can I select by most recent reviews programmatically through selenium ?

Basically I want to see all the reviews of the hotel sorted by Most recent instead of most useful, but since by default are ordered by most useful I need to switch through the dropdown programmatically.

I've tried this way :

```
        Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gsr\"]/g-lightbox/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/g-dropdown-menu/g-popup/div[2]/g-menu")));
        select.deselectByIndex(1);
```

but I'm getting an exception(`org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException`) saying :

```
Element should have been "select" but was "g-dropdown-menu"
```

Is there a way to simulate a click on a CSS dropdown element like this with Selenium web driver ?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question correctly. I was able to trace down the `xpath` till `//g-dropdown-menu/g-popup` but not beyond that. Can you update us the manual step please?

Comment: Basically I want to see all the reviews of the hotel sorted by Most recent instead of most useful, but since by default are ordered by most useful I need to switch through the dropdown programmatically. What I need to do is select on the dropdown most recent using selenium . Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Analysis:**

Selenium Java API: Select.class only suitable for dropdown which use HTML select tag. For dropdown implment by other way, like JQuery dropdown plugin, Select class not support, for such dropdown you need to click on the drop down to make the options to display out, then choose the option you wanted.

**Solution:**

```
public void selectSortby(String sortBy) {
  // click on dropdown to expand options
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[span[text()='Sort by:']]//g-dropdown-button").click();
  // choose option
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//g-menu-item/div[text()='"+sortBy+"']")).click();
}
```